# Accessing postgres without being root users

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I have created a postgres database in postgres named "databaseName". Now I can access this data2database through

```
 su - postgres
```

and then typing my password

Then I enter into the database through: psql databaseName

I have created users of this database through:

```
   createuser -P userName1
```

Now I dont want the users of the database to access the database as root user. Now when the  users try to login into postgres as

```
 su - postgres -u userName1 
        or through
 psql databaseName -u userName1
```

I get error...can someone guide me as to how the users can get access to postgres and database without being root user?

Comment: Please never write "I get error". What error? Exactly? Copy and paste the exact error text into your question.

Comment: @CraigRinger Sure I'll keep this in mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configure `pg_hba.conf` to accept `peer` connections over unix sockets or `ident` connections over `host` (tcp) connections. If you prefer you can use `md5` to use password authentication instead.

By default `psql` will connect with the same username as your local OS username; this can be overridden by the `-U` flag, eg:

```
psql -U myusername thedatabase
```

Note that it's `-U` not `-u` (it's upper case).

This is all covered in detail in the PostgreSQL documentation; see:

- [Client Authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html)
- [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)
- [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

BTW, if you want to run commands as the `postgres` user, rather than `su`'ing you can just write:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I am new to postgres therefore I am not getting how to configure ph_hba.conf. I'll be highly thankful if you can guide me in configuring it..I am working on a linux server through command line interface. Hearty thanks again for replying

Comment: @user1778824 Read the "client authentication" chapter of the documentation, it sound explain everything you need. I can't just tell you how to configure it; if there were one right way to set it up we wouldn't make it a config file at all, we'd just have the server automatically work that way. It's a config file because different people want Pg to work different ways for different situations.

Comment: @user1778824 Without knowing your exact needs and situation it's hard to say what you need - especially as you haven't mentioned your distro, shown your current `pg_hba.conf`, said how you want to authenticate users, etc.